# Add shutter speed to the function keys on a Nikon Z7

Tags: nikon

How do I map the shutter speed settings to one of the function (fn1 or fn2) buttons to use with the command dial? The default settings only let you change the shutter speed via the touch screen, and I haven't yet figured out how to remap buttons.

Comment: In what mode? I haven't worked with the Z, but earlier ones the functionality was mode-dependant.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

By default shutter speed is on the main (rear) command dial when in Manual or Shutter priority modes.

And if easy exposure compensation is enabled SS will be on the main command dial when in Aperture priority mode.
But that assumes that either auto ISO is not enabled, or it has reached a limit (exposure compensation adjusts ISO first if it can).

You can change which command dial controls what.